# Materialize CSS Select With Browser-Default On Mobile

Tags: css, html, materialize

I'm working on a form with the Materialize CSS framework and I'm having a difficult time with the way a select box with the browser-default class is rending on mobile.[image]

As you can see from the image, the select box sits much tighter to the Zip field compared to the rest of my fields.

I have some inline styling applied to the label and a fair amount of custom css to help align other items and customize the color of the lines and the select box arrow, but I have not been able to determine what is different in this case.

In this example, the user enters their street and zip code, then the city and state are reveal with a select box for those areas in the US that may share a zip code.

I've tried several variations of my CSS with no success and even media queries - however, if a user resizes a desktop browser window the media queries start moving the select box in unwanted ways. I'm at a total loss as to why the spacing is so different for just that one select box on tablets and phones.

If anyone is familiar with this kind of issue and has a solution, I'd certainly welcome it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row ctyst" style="margin-bottom: -10px; display: block; margin-top: -10px;">
            <!--Residential City State Roll Down -->
                <div style="margin-bottom: 36px;" class="select-container">
                    <div id="home_city" style="margin-top: 8px;">
                        <label for="home_city" class="active" style="font-size: 16px; top: -5px; left: -4px;">City</label>
                        <select name="home_city" id="home_city" class="browser-default validate sbx xbsl chosen"><option value=""></option></select>
                    </div>
                    <p id="home_city_err" class="errp" style="display: none;"> </p>
                </div>        

                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" name="home_state" class="" value="" readonly="" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #757575;">
                    <p class="errp" id="home_state_err" style="display: none;"> </p>
                    <label for="home_state" class="active">State</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the CSS I'm using on the select box and input fields:

```
     select {
      padding: 6px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #585858;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
      border-radius: 0;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }
     .select-container {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
     .select-container:after {
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
     .select-container:after {
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 5px solid transparent;
      top: 15px;
      left: 312px;
      border-top: 8px solid #585858;
    }
     select::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
     .chosen {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #757575;
    }
     .select-container {
      position: relative;
    }
     .select-container label {
      position: absolute;
      top: -15px;
      left: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #757575;
      transition: all 0.1s linear;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    input {
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #585858;
    }
    input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
     .input-field input[type=text].valid,  
.input-field input[type=email].valid,  
.input-field input[type=tel].valid,  
.input-field input[type=password].valid {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
        color: #757575;
        font-size: 16px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #757575;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the other CSS related to these classes in addition to some dummy data so we can get a full picture of what you're working with?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the CSS.